# Does changing api names of a field which exist in a change set gets synced

Tags: change-set

I had a bunch of fields added to a outbound change set, after adding them to the change set I updated the api name of those fields. so will the change set have the field names with updated api names or will it have the old field api names

Comment: The change set content is frozen at the time of creation, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is No.

After you upload a change set, you can't change its contents. If you need to add dependent components to a change set you already uploaded, clone the change set, add the dependent components, and then upload it again.

> The cloned change set includes the latest changes to its components
> source.

Refer the [Change Sets Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.changesets_best_practices.htm&type=5)